# How to perform correct useState within these code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with the render, so I've been told to set the table I use as a state so the data could update correctly.

The table I'm using:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
  <View>
    <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9' }}>
      <Row
        data={this.state.tableHead}
        widthArr={this.state.widthArr}
        style={styles.header}
        textStyle={styles.text}
      />
    </Table>
    <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
      <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9' }}>
        {this.state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
          <Row
            key={index}
            data={rowData}
            widthArr={this.state.widthArr}
            style={[styles.row, index % 2 && { backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7' }]}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
        ))
        //this.state.myState
        }
      </Table>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

It's working under `render()` and I try to make a `setState` `onPress` option to activate it, I did something like:

```
updateState = () =>
  this.setState({
    myState: this.state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
      <Row
        key={index}
        data={rowData}
        widthArr={this.state.widthArr}
        style={[styles.row, index % 2 && { backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7' }]}
        textStyle={styles.text}
      />
    )),
  })
```

But can't get it to work.

Comment: what do you want to setState? What do your state 'myState' hold?

Comment: myState is a try to hold all this table starting from scrollView, but it let me only use one thing so I tried to hold the map function. 
it draws an table with some data i pick from db, but updates only change when i change a state or click another time on a button

Answer (score 1):

Add a `toggle` state. This state will change on every `onPress` event.

(for the sample below, I'm using `onClick`)

```js
const {useState} = React;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
    };
    this.data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = {
          () => this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })
        }>
          {this.state.toggle ? 'hide' : 'show'}
        </button>
        {this.state.toggle ? this.data.map(d => (
          <div>{d}</div>
        )) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: OP is definitely not using functional components given the use of `this.state` You should update the answer to give a solution on the class components as well

Comment: but what am I suppose to put on my state?
or I just toggle the " { } " i have as a <Table> ?

Comment: @Try2prog the idea is to toggle the table using [conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)